# Returning null exception on linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

There's probably a very simple reason for this, but when hydrating an object I'm keep getting a "value cannot be null" exception:

```
public class MyObject
{
   public MyObject() {
    }  

    public virtual IList<MemberObject> MemberObjects { get; protected set; }              

    [JsonProperty] public virtual SubObject LastMemberObject {
        get { return MemberObjects.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault() ?? null; }
    }
 }
```

When hydrating the object, if the MemberObjects is null, LastMemberObject throws a cannot be null exception. What's the deal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If MemberObjects is null you will get this exception if you attempt to access a method or property such as OrderByDescending. Try this:

```
[JsonProperty] public virtual SubObject LastMemberObject {
        get { return MemberObjects != null? MemberObjects.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault() : null; }
    }
```

Comment: I knew it was simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the object `MemberObjects` is null, you can't call any instance methods on it.

```
[JsonProperty]
public virtual SubObject LastMemberObject {
    get {
        return MemberObjects != null
           ? MemberObjects.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault()
           : null; }
    }
```

Also, when you're calling the `FirstOrDefault()` method, this "default has to be specified as well.

```
MemberObjects
.OrderByDescending (x => x.CreatedOn)
.Default (something)
.FirstOrDefault ();
```

Comment: `OrderByDescending` isn't an instance method, it is an extension method defined in a static class.